# PHP generated XML parsing failed

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, domdocument

In my CodeIgniter 2.x project with PHP 5.3.x I use following function to render Dom Document as XML response. Every things are goes fine. But generated XML parsing failed due to some malformed unexpected text (non-whitespace text outside root element).

```
function renderDOMAsXML(DOMDocument &$dom, $format = true, $status = 200){
    $dom->formatOutput  = $format;
    $controller         = &get_instance();

    $controller->output->set_status_header($status);
    $controller->output->set_header('Content-type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');
    $controller->output->set_output($dom->saveXML());
}
```

for my curiosity I decoded the malformed  unexpected text (non-whitespace text outside root element) as hexadecimal format as following.

```
\x00ef\x00bb\x00bf\x00ef\x00bb\x00bf\x00ef\x00bb\x00bf\x00ef\x00bb\x00bf\x00ef\x00bb\x00bf
```

or

```
\x{00ef}\x{00bb}\x{00bf}\x{00ef}\x{00bb}\x{00bf}\x{00ef}\x{00bb}\x{00bf}\x{00ef}\x{00bb}\x{00bf}\x{00ef}\x{00bb}\x{00bf}
```

or like this

```
∩╗┐∩╗┐∩╗┐∩╗┐∩╗┐
```

I could not realize what's the wrong. What are the  malformed  unexpected text (non-whitespace text outside root element)? are they any header information? How do I could skip them as I want to render it as XML response for browser.

Comment: Output the XML without the CI methods to find out whether it's an issue with DOM or with CI.

Comment: Its was the issue of php file encoding and was my mistake to create some file with Unicode encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Actually no problem on your code. Only problem on your ***`php file encoding`***. Never ever save any file on ***`Unicode encoding`*** like ***`UTF-8|Unicode|Unicodebig endian`*** . Only save your php file as ***`ANSI Encoding`***. If you create a php file with ***`UTF-8|Unicode|Unicodebig endian`*** these encoding your ***`php code`*** automatically ***`echo`*** following malformed unexpected text (non-whitespace text outside root element).

```
\x{00ef}\x{00bb}\x{00bf}\x{00ef}\x{00bb}\x{00bf}\x{00ef}\x{00bb}\x{00bf}\x{00ef}\x{00bb}\x{00bf}\x{00ef}\x{00bb}\x{00bf}
```

That's why your most latest browser unable to parse your xml response and due to cause xml parsing error. Actually *malformed unexpected text (non-whitespace text outside root element)* may be the header information for ***`Unicode encoding`*** file format.

These unexpected text always place at the beginning of your response but never interrupted when you are using others content type response header if you are using ***`Unicode encoded`*** php files .

If you are falling such type of problem as soon as possible convert all of your file encoding into ***`ANSI Encoding`***.